# Tag the maximum value per group using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to tag the maximum value per group using dplyr. The following code works fine, but it is very cumbersome and involves merging datasets together which takes time. So I am looking for a code that will identify the maximum value in a simpler way.

```
year <- rep(2014:2015, length.out = 10000)
group <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
value <- sample(10000, replace = T)

dta <- data.frame(year = year, group = group, value = value)

library(dplyr)
dta2 <- dta %>% group_by(year, group) %>% top_n(n=1)  
dta2$tag=1

dta3 <- merge(dta, dta2, by=c("year", "group", "value"), all = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `year` and `group` you can compare `value` to the maximum `value` in the group and assign 1 to it if they are similar or 0 otherwise.

```
library(dplyr)

dta %>% 
  group_by(year, group) %>%
  mutate(tag = as.integer(value == max(value)))
```

If the maximum value is found at 2 places in the group this will tag both of them. You can use `which.max` to tag only the 1st value.

```
dta %>% 
  group_by(year, group) %>%
  mutate(tag = as.integer(row_number() == which.max(value)))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dta)[, tag := +(value == max(value)), .(year, group)]
```